# how to validate http form data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, webserver

Suppose my webpage `test.html` is sending form data to webpage `callback.html` on same domain, how can I validate if form data is sent by `test.html` not by anybody else? Think `test.html` as trusted source for `callback.html`.

```
<form action="callback.html" methos="post">
<input type="hidden" id="abc" value="User is not authenticated"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You can try passing a cookie with a machine key embedded that the other machine knows about.  You can use a cert also I believe to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only secure way to ensure that a POST is coming from a trusted source is to make sure that the transaction involves some information that only your site knows.  There are different ways to do this, but a simple one is to use the value of your session cookie as a form field value. Your server would then reject POST transactions that lacked that parameter.

If your transactions are not secure (https) then there's not much point anyway.

*edit* — I'll mention that an alternative, if your POST transactions are initiated with XHR, is to add a special "X-Something" header to the request.

Comment: My transaction is secure . If hacker view source and get form field value , after that he made post request by including this form field , will this transaction is rejected by server ?

Comment: @Arsalan the session token needs to be unique for every user. A "hacker" that can log in to your site can then only attack his/her own account.

Comment: What if webpage is authenticating user from facebook server using   oauth2.0 user agent flow and then telling server if user is authenticated or not ?

Comment: @Arsalan well that's fine; once a user has authenticated, you have to keep track of their session one way or another. Almost always, that's done by keeping a session cookie whose value is some securely-random string.

Comment: User opens a webpage , see the unique session value , makes fake http post along with session claiming I m authenticated and these are my details . My system take those details and submit in database and make this session as authenticated session . I dont think this is good option .

Comment: @Arsalan if the user has authenticated, then they've got a valid session and should be able to access your site. That's how the entire Internet works.

Comment: I agree with all your points thats why I accepted your post as my answer but my scenario is little different here . I m authenticating user at client side by using facebook-oauth client side flow and then telling server if user is authenticated by facebook server or not . These steps are performed by redirecting user to facebook server and then facebook server sends token to request users data directly from browser using get or post request .

Comment: @Arsalan well your server will get the access token when the user has authorized.  You will then have to keep a cookie to know that subsequent HTTP transactions are for that authorized user. You still have to validate each operation to make sure that the user is only performing allowed transactions. Once the user has the session cookie, you cannot control exactly how the user posts transactions to your server. All you can do is disallow invalid operations.

Comment: well my server will not get access token because facebook-oauth2.0 client side flow will not send access token to server , facebook server just redirect user to registered url(http://mysite.com#access-token=0001) after authenticating user . # in url prevents sending access token in query string . I have to manually send (using form field value) access token and authenticity of user . But here anyone can send any access token and authenticity.

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with OAuth 2.0 so I'm not sure how it works; if it is actually an authentication service, then there has to be **some** way that your server can be told that a user has been authenticated.

Comment: Point you have told is good for oauth server side flow but I m still finding way to secure client side flow . But as you are not familiar you might not be getting what I m saying . Anyway thank you from the bottom of my heart for your time :)